# Python subclass overridden method with different signature, so base class method is not called. Why is that?

Tags: python, inheritance, overriding

```
class UnionFind:

    def __init__(self, n):
        self.parents = list(range(n))
        self.ranks = [0]*n

    def _find(self, x):  # _find -> find

        if self.parents[x] != x:
            self.parents[x] = self._find(self.parents[x])  # _find -> find

        return self.parents[x]

    def _union(self, x, y):

        px = self._find(x)  # _find -> find
        py = self._find(y)  # _find -> find

        if px == py: return False

        if self.ranks[px] < self.ranks[py]:
            py, px = px, py

        self.parents[py] = px
        if self.ranks[px] == self.ranks[py]:
            self.ranks[px] += 1
        return True

class Island(UnionFind):
    
    def __init__(self, m, n):
        super().__init__(m*n+1)
        self.m = m
        self.n = n
        self.islands = 0
        self.occupied = set()
        
    def _coordToIdx(self, i, j):
        return i*self.n+j+1;
    
    def addIsland(self, i, j):
        if (i,j) in self.occupied: return
        self.islands += 1
        self.occupied.add((i,j))
        for di, dj in [(0,1),(1,0),(0,-1),(-1,0)]:
            ni, nj = i+di, j+dj
            if 0<=ni<self.m and 0<=nj<self.n and (ni,nj) in self.occupied:
                self.union(i,j,ni,nj)
                
    def getIslands(self):
        return self.islands
    
    def find(self, i, j):
        return super().find(self._coordToIdx(i,j))
    
    def union(self, i1,j1, i2,j2):
        x, y = self._coordToIdx(i1,j1), self._coordToIdx(i2,j2)
        if super()._union(x, y):
            self.islands -= 1

class Solution:
    def numIslands2(self, m: int, n: int, positions: List[List[int]]) -> List[int]:
        ans = []
        island = Island(m,n)
        for i, j in positions:
            island.addIsland(i,j)
            ans.append(island.getIslands())
        return ans
```

I have a subclass called `Island` inherited from `UnionFind`. Both classes have method called `find` and `union`. In order to make it work here, I have to change the method in  class `UnionFind` to be a different name (`_find` and `_union`). I have added a few comments in the code showing that if I replace `_find` with `find` I will get a runtime error.

It appears to me that the problem is subclass `Island` has the same method `find` as the superclass `UnionFind`, but with a different number of parameters. When `super()._union` is called from the subclass, it is trying to call `Island::find` instead of `UnionFind::find`. Here is what I don't understand why that would happen.

Comment: Runtime Error
TypeError: find() missing 1 required positional argument: 'j'
    px = self.find(x)
Line 16 in _union (Solution.py)
    if super()._union(x, y):
Line 58 in union (Solution.py)
    self.union(i,j,ni,nj)
Line 48 in addIsland (Solution.py)
    island.addIsland(i,j)
Line 66 in numIslands2 (Solution.py)
    ret = Solution().numIslands2(param_1, param_2, param_3)
Line 98 in _driver (Solution.py)
    _driver()
Line 109 in <module> (Solution.py)

Answer (score 0):

`self.find()` always uses the `find` method of whatever type `self` is.  If you call `self.find(..)` inside a `UnionFind` method, but `self` is an `Island`, it will call `Island.find()`.  That's the way it works in most object-oriented languages.

If you want to specifically call `UnionFind.find`, your are doing the right thing in creating a `_find` that isn't inherited.  I'd probably even call it `__find` so it can't even be inherited by accident.